# How can I create One single UV mapping space with 3 or 4 different Uv mapping from different objects?

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

I have a doubt , I am making assets for my project. I've 4 different objects , for example a candle , a rock , chest and one bottle , all these props have got their own UV mapping coordinates.

There is the "AtlasTexture" - their own UV map made with the TextureAtlas addon...
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs7T7.jpg]

How can I create an AtlasTexture with previously baked Cycles material on texture space ? (UVmapping is done for every object).

I noticed that IF I create Textures first the AtlasTexture, whenever I try to scale the UV from respected Textured Objects, the UV on the Atlas becomes distorted.

[image: screenshot 2]
  In their own UV maps for every single object I use Cycles baked textures, BEFORE  to create an atlas , I think the textures will become distorted...

Comment: Links seem broken. Please fix

Comment: Have you tried the [Atlas addon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oq72vP2Yfj4)?

Comment: Yes I try with the Atlas addon, even the Multi editing addon, is the same ,at least in the essentials...but I think the problem is in "average scale" and  "pack island" this stuff sometimes make issues...cause for example I ve texture the chest and when I try to pack the island for the chest, it self crash on the scale, which means the texture I ve made make ugly distortion on x,y,z...

Comment: I never had an issue with distortion and I am using the Texture Atlas add-on pretty often. Three essential tips: 1. Always apply the size to your object.  2. You need to unwrap all the objects before using the add-on. 3. Don't use any other unwrap options than no_unwrap, then proceed with "StartManualUnwrap". Oh, and don't forget to finish with "FinishManualUnwrap".

Comment: perphaps my workflow is bad, I have texture painted all my objects, then I use cycles nodes to combine with the TexturedDiffuse I ve made on internal.... I ve make individual UVs mapping for all the object, then I use the atlas and suffers the distortion on the "chest" object... but the distortions appears whenver I use the "Pack island" ...

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/pgmrX see this picture , for example the chest, the original and first UV was the real size of the chest, but when I create an atlas texture I must scale the chest...cause I need space for the rest objects ( 4 on scene) , but if scale the chest to make space, (I put the island down to the right, (as in the pic) but if you see the 3dviewport is a mess.

Comment: Well, what is shown on your screenshot is exactly what I asked. You unwrapped a chest. Textured it with image textures. Created Texture Atlas. Decided to resize UV map to map all the UV islands into UV space. All the textures became .. unexpected. And obviously, because new coordinates for UV islands no longer correspond to ones which were used for texturing. So do *not* scale / rotate // anyhow edit UV map after texturing (or remake texturing).

Comment: can you recommend me the workflow? I think I must resize all the uv first, apply the average scale ? can I avoid the Pack island? cause I think sometimes the "pack island" deform the  space that I ve designed for objects, but sometimes I use "rotate" to keep the size .

Comment: The "Pack Islands" feature is not intended to be used *after* you created the texture map with the Texture Atlas add-on. You create the Texture Atlas, use average scale, move the UVs around or use "Pack Islands" and ***then*** bake all individual texture maps to the texture atlas.

Comment: The face displays the texture according to their UV coordinate and pack islands only moves UVs so you will have to make sure you move the pixels in the image file accordingly as well. Often you achieve this by making your atlas UVs a separate UV layer and texture bake a new atlas image afterwards. Look into Blender texture baking tutorials.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/qorTS  this is the result for one object, I have averaged scaled and then Pack island and then scale and put it near the top and the right size of this UV map for Texture Atlas , notice I ve 2 UV map, one is the original UV for every object and the second UV map is for Atlas .